# How Does a camera convert from clip space into screen space?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to render a bunch of 3d points into 2d canvas without webgl.
I thought clip space and screen space are the same thing, and camera is used to convert from 3d world space to 2d screen space,
but apperently they are not.

So on webgl, when setting `gl_Position`, it's in clip space,
later this position is converted to screen space by webgl, and `gl_FragCoord` is set.
How is this calculation is done and where?

And Camera matrix and view projection matrices has nothing to do with converting clip space to screen space.
I can have a 3d world space that fit's into clip space, and I wouldn't need to use a camera right?

If all my assumptions are true, I need to learn how to convert from clip space into screen space.
Here's my code:

```
const uMatrix = mvpMatrix(modelMatrix(transform));

 // transform each vertex into 2d screen space
vertices = vertices.map(vertex => {
  let res = mat4.multiplyVector(uMatrix, [...vertex, 1.0]);
  // res is vec4 element, in clip space,
  // how to transform this into screen space?
  return [res[0], res[1]];
});


// viewProjectionMatrix calculation
const mvpMatrix = modelMatrix => {
  const { pos: camPos, target, up } = camera;
  const { fov, aspect, near, far } = camera;

  let camMatrix = mat4.lookAt(camPos, target, up);
  let viewMatrix = mat4.inverse(camMatrix);

  let projectionMatrix = mat4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);

  let viewProjectionMatrix = mat4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);

  return mat4.multiply(viewProjectionMatrix, modelMatrix);
};
```

The camera mentioned in [this article](https://cantelope.org/tiny_3D/) transforms clip space to screen space, If so it shouldn't be named a camera right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First the geometry is clipped, according to the clip space coordinate (`gl_Position`). The clip space coordinate is a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). The condition for a homogeneous coordinate to be in clip space is:

```
-w <=  x, y, z  <= w.
```

The clip space coordinate is transformed to a [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) in normalized device space, by [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide):

```
ndc_position = gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w
```

The normalized device space is a cube, with the left bottom front of (-1, -1, -1) and the right top back of (1, 1, 1).

The x and y component of the normalized device space coordinate is linear mapped to the viewport, which is set by `gl.viewport` (See [WebGL Viewport](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#2.3)). The viewport is a rectangle with an origin (`x`, `y`) and a `width` and a `height`:

```
xw = (ndc_position.x + 1) * (width / 2) + x
yw = (ndc_position.y + 1) * (height / 2 ) + y
```

`xw` and `yw` can be accessed by `gl_FragCoord.xy` in the fragment shader.

The z component of the normalized device space coordinate is linear mapped to the depth range, which is by default [0.0, 1.0], but can be set by `gl.depthRange`. See [Viewport Depth Range](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6.14). The depth range consists of a `near` value and a `far` value. `far` has to be greater than `near` and both values have to be in [0.0, 1.0]:

```
depth = (ndc_position.z + 1) * (far-near) / 2 + near
```

The `depth` can be accessed by `gl_FragCoord.z` in the fragment shader.

All this operations are done automatically in the rendering pipeline and are part of the Vertex Post-Processing.